# Mixing absolute and relative layers sources in QGIS project

Tags: qgis, path

I want to mix relative and absolute paths in the QGIS project file.

Is it possible to set relative paths for most of the layers in the QGIS project file, and to set absolute paths for a minor part of the layers?

Example folder scturcute (requested by
[@Babel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88814/babel)):

`C:\DELETE\folder\1\1.bmp`

`C:\DELETE\folder\1\project.qgz` <= original project

`C:\DELETE\folder\2\1.bmp`

`C:\DELETE\folder\2\project.qgz` <= original project copy 1

`C:\DELETE\folder\project.qgz`   <= original project copy 2

`C:\DELETE\absolute\absolute.bmp`

`G:\absolute\absolute.bmp` <= the drive letter is **G**

Now if you open the diffferent project files you will see that `C:\DELETE\absolute\absolute.bmp` source is broken (it should be absolute insead of relative):

original project:

> [image: original project]

original project copy 1:

> [image: original project copy 1]

original project copy 2:

> [image: original project copy 2]

Comment: Afaik, relative/absolute path settings are set globally for the project as a whole. Why not set to relative path and then define an absolute path where necessary? Should work. Or doesn't it?

Comment: @Babel The problem is that I copy/paste the project file into different folders, and some layer sources break and I have to fix them each time. I want to set absolute paths for some layers and forget about this problem.

Comment: How can relative paths still work when copying the project to other folders? Can you provide an actual example of folder structure (even if fake) to understand the problem?

Comment: I don't know if this would work so I'd try it on a copy, but if you edit the qgs project file in a text editor to set absolute paths for the layers you want while the default remains relative, would it still work in that location, and then work in another?  If it does in that case you might edit the project and save it and see if it still works that way.  I always set my projects up in matching locations on different computers or used QPackage to keep  two different locations matched but there is duplication of data and copying time.

Comment: @John It works, but when you save the project again, the path becomes relative again.